# How to import data from a file and append it to a Python list?

Tags: python, list, import

This is what I've tried.

```
foo = {}
foo['bar'] = [{'a': '1', 'b': '2'}, {'c':'3', 'd':'4'} ]
import othervalues
```

This is the content of othervalues.py

```
foo['bar'].append({'e': '5', 'f': '6'})
```

However when I try to run this, it fails saying that foo isn't defined.

How can I append to the original list by using values stored in another file?

Comment: Either: 1. import the new dictionary (`{'e': '5', 'f': '6'}`) then append it as needed; or 2. import a function that takes `foo` and appends the new data. As written, your code makes no sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In othervalues you could have:

```
def fooadd(foo):
    foo['bar'].append({'e': '5', 'f': '6'})
```

And then, in your normal code:

```
import othervalues
othervalues.fooadd(foo)
```